# Merge [xbox] and [xbox360]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

Can we merge [xbox](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/xbox) and [xbox360](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/xbox360)? I think all of the questions tagged with [xbox](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/xbox) refer to Xbox 360.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like someone already went ahead and did it.